# Как узнать размер архива до распаковки?

Tags: архивация, linux

Имеется большой сильно сжатый архив.tar.xz. После распаковки он вырастет в размере примерно в 10 - 15 раз. И места на диске может не хватить. Можно ли узнать суммарный размер каталога, в который выльется распаковка архива, еще до начала распаковки?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте опцию -l

```
xz -l архив.tar.xz
```

Пример вывода

```
Strms  Blocks   Compressed Uncompressed  Ratio  Check   Filename    1       1    761,0 KiB  3 170,0 KiB  0,240  CRC64   архив.tar.xz
```

Столбец Uncompressed - это ожидаемый размер после распаковки.